# Can anyone help in $\int_0^\pi (\sin x )^{\cos x} dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following definite integral;

> $\int_0^\pi (\sin x )^{\cos x} dx$?

Comment: @OmG Your input is wrong. You computed the integral of the function $x\cdot \sin(x)^{\cos(x)}$ instead of $\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}$. It does not alter the fact that it [does not converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Epi+sin(x)%5Ecos(x)) but I would say it is important to be precise concerning the integrand.

Answer (score 3):

The integral does not exist, because $\sin(\pi-\epsilon) = \epsilon + o(\epsilon^3)$ and $\cos(\pi-\epsilon) = -1 + \epsilon^2/2 + o(\epsilon^3),$ i.e. the integrand has a pole at $x=\pi.$